# Weird script stack entries at block #227837?

Tags: script, coinbase-transaction, btcguild

At block [227837](https://blockexplorer.com/block/000000000000002579bc6db5a836a81d3a217b549721a0ef1facdf8f069ce0cb) , the coinbase TX

> e35ca7413b61397a49551fea6ebb540988afcf4a2d0e750773d38eb11b138f40

has the following script:

> 03fd790304000037e4124d696e656420627920425443204775696c6408000000fb00001e0b

Which translates to:

```
03 = push the next 3 bytes to the stack ==> ok
fd7903 , the 3 bytes which are the block height ==> ok
04 = push the next 4 bytes to the stack ==> ok
000037e4 , the 4 bytes which are pushed to the stack ==> what's that?
12 == push the next 18 bytes to the stack ==> ok
4d696e656420627920425443204775696c64 = "Mined by BTC Guild" ==> ok
08 == push the next 8 bytes to the stack ==> ok
000000fb00001e0b ==> what's that?
```

So, what is the meaning of "000037e4" and "000000fb00001e0b"? Are they just some pool related nonce bytes, or is there a deeper meaning related to the signature?

Answer (score 3):

Coinbase inputs have no requirements to be valid scripts, or any particular data at all other than the block height defined in BIP34.

Comment: That is fine, but why did BTC Guide bothered to add the extra data (total 4+8 bytes) into the script?

Comment: Miners will often put extra data into the coinbase script as an extra nonoce. So instead of having to reselect all of the transactions, they can just change a value in the coinbase transaction to get a different merkle root and thus a different block.